# What is the closest magnesis-able chest near Layanaru tower?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I wanted to execute a glitch Kleric talked about in their video, where they got infinite guardian parts. However, I need a chest to do so. I have done a search, but could not find one.
I do not have access to the wiki, so can someone tell me where the closest magnesis-able chest is relative to Layanaru tower?

Comment: Side note: I do have the DLC.

Comment: You can spawn chests using a botw amiibo. I don't know which chests are magnesisable.

Comment: Does Revali spawn one? I got a revali amiibo today...

Comment: I guess it will spawn one. I don't have that one but all the BOTW series amiibo's I've seen spawn a chest. Except that time I got the legendary horse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good question and an easy one to answer. Teleport into Lanayru Tower, and walk forward. Near the base of a cliff there will be some rocks to explode with a bomb. there will be a chest that contains some fire arrows. Open this chest, then use the infinite parts glitch.
YoU should note however it's much easier to do this near Hyrule Castle courtyard, as the area around Lanaryu tower is difficult for moving guardians.

Comment: Thanks! Quick question: Will the RUinGuardian break if I use a bomb to move it?

Comment: Gaurdians cannot break. Nor can it be moved if not already pushed with a chest.